# Solve gives a solution which is contradicted by an example

Tags: equation-solving, algebra

I have the problem as described in the title. Here is the code:

```
Remove["Global`*"]
L3 = 2 c1 + 4 c2 + Sqrt[24 c1^2 + 16 c1 c2 + 16 c2^2]
L4 = 1/2 (4 c1 + 8 c2 - 2 Sqrt[24 c1^2 + 16 c1 c2 + 16 c2^2])
Solve[{L3 == K3, L4 == K4}, {c1, c2}];
Set @@@ %[[1]];
K3 = 1; K4 = 2;
FullSimplify[{K3, K4}]
FullSimplify[{L3, L4}]
```

The output is

```
{1, 2}
{2, 1}
```

Since the equations that have been solved for are L3==K3, L4==K4, how can it be that when I specify values for K3,K4, I find L3 and L4 interchanged? What is this? There was not even a Warning Message (MMA 8).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Solve[{L3==1,L4==2},{c1,c2}]` returns an empty set.  I do not understand what you want your `K3 =1; K4=2;` line to do, since, as written, it plays no role in your solution as far as I can tell.

Comment: You are right, there is only a solution when K3>K4. This information is not given by Solve. I was not aware of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can gain more insight by looking at the symbolic form of the solutions

```
Remove["Global`*"]
L3 = 2 c1 + 4 c2 + Sqrt[24 c1^2 + 16 c1 c2 + 16 c2^2];
L4 = 1/2 (4 c1 + 8 c2 - 2 Sqrt[24 c1^2 + 16 c1 c2 + 16 c2^2]);
Solve[{L3 == K3, L4 == K4}, {c1, c2}];
Set @@@ %[[1]];
FullSimplify[{{L3, K3}, {L4, K4}}]
FullSimplify[{{L3, K3}, {L4, K4}}, Assumptions -> Element[K3 | K4, Reals]]
```

As you can see it's a matter of choosing which branch of the Sqrt to take.

```
{{1/2 (K3 + Sqrt[(K3 - K4)^2] + K4), K3}, {1/2 (K3 - Sqrt[(K3 - K4)^2] + K4), K4}}


{{Piecewise[{{K3, K3 >= K4}}, K4], K3}, {Piecewise[{{K3, K3 < K4}}, K4], K4}}
```

Comment: Thank you. So to summarize: The symbolic solution implies some constraints, in this example it is K3>K4. This is due to Mathematica choosing automatically a specific branch of Sqrt?

Comment: It doesn't until you assume the solution is real. I included the fully general complex solution to show that.

Answer (score 1):

This is really a comment, but for ease of reading...

Adjusting your code slightly, we note some useful information:

```
Remove["Global`*"]
L3 = 2 c1 + 4 c2 + Sqrt[24 c1^2 + 16 c1 c2 + 16 c2^2];
L4 = 1/2 (4 c1 + 8 c2 - 2 Sqrt[24 c1^2 + 16 c1 c2 + 16 c2^2]);
soln = Solve[{L3 == K3, L4 == K4}, {c1, c2}];
{L3, L4} /. First@soln // Simplify

(* {1/2 (K3 + Sqrt[(K3 - K4)^2] + K4), 1/2 (K3 - Sqrt[(K3 - K4)^2] + K4)} *)
```

It looks like K3 and K4 can be interchanged without affecting the result.  Is this expected behavior for your system?

Comment: I have to think about this.